# How Can I Prevent Xamarin Studio from Downloading Older Mono Updates?

Tags: macos, mono, xamarin-studio

I am running Xamarin Studio 4.2.4 on Beta update channel on OS X. I have just installed Mono 3.4.0 MDK. After the update, I started Xamarin Studio and it correctly defaults to the new Mono version.

Sadly, it also opened the 'check for updates' dialog and started downloading Mono 3.2.6 MDK.

Is there a way to prevent Xamarin Studio from downloading older versions of Mono, or disable downloading of Mono updates, while still allowing other updates (Xamarin.iOS, etc) to be downloaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to `Xamarin Studio > Check for updates...` and disabled the `Check automatically` option.

I've also joined the "alpha" update channel, which currently supports Mono framework 3.4.0.

Comment: Thanks, I did that too for now. Sadly, that doesn't help with receiving other updates I care about (iOS, etc). Alpha channel seems to be the solution for now, thanks.